# How to create a rounded hexagon with border using CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm sharing the design below.

[image]

And my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/09h5coq8/

```
.hex {
        position: relative;
        margin: 1em auto;
        width: 200px; 
        height: 346.4px;
        border-radius: 20px/10px;
        background: rgb(139,21,186);
        background: linear-gradient(70deg, rgba(139,21,186,1) 0%, rgba(64,13,104,1) 100%);
        background-size:cover;
        transition: opacity .5s;
        transform: rotate(20deg);
        margin-top:125px;
        }
        .hex:before, .hex:after {
        position: absolute;
        width: inherit; height: inherit;
        border-radius: inherit;
        background: inherit;
        content: '';
        }
        .hex:before {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
            transform: rotate(60deg);
            background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(139,21,186,1) 0%, rgba(64,13,104,1) 100%);
        }
        .hex:after {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
            transform: rotate(-60deg);
            background: linear-gradient(-50deg, rgba(139,21,186,1) 0%, rgba(64,13,104,1) 100%);
        }
       .hex-inside {
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px; 
        height: 259.8px;
        border-radius: 15px/7.5px;
        background: grey;
        transition: opacity .5s;
        z-index:99;
        left:25px;
        top:43.3px;
        }
        .hex-inside:before, .hex-inside:after {
        position: absolute;
        width: inherit; height: inherit;
        border-radius: inherit;
        background: inherit;
        content: '';
        }
        .hex-inside:before {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
            transform: rotate(60deg);
        }
        .hex-inside:after {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
        transform: rotate(-60deg);
        }



<div class="hex">
        <div class="hex-inside">
            
        </div>  
    </div>
```

As you can see; my code has more "sharpen corners" broken "gradient" and not enough feelings.
Whats wrong?

How can this be possible to make with "pure css and javascript".

Do I have to make it with SVG?

Comment: Well, if you're going to include javascript but not SVG, then you may as well use a canvas. If you do use a canvas, you're not really that far from SVG though. I think the main problem will be masking. You might be able to fake the rounded hexagon with `clip-path` and lots of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea using `clip-path` and [gooey filter](https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/):

```css
.box {
  width: 300px; /* adjust this to control the size of the shape */
  margin: 20px;
  transform:rotate(-20deg);
}

.box,
.box > div > div{
  filter: url('#goo'); /* the SVG filter (adjust the "stDeviation" value to control the radius) */
}

.box > div {
  padding: 20px; /* thickness of the gradient */
  /* your gradient here */
  background: linear-gradient(70deg, rgba(139,21,186,1), rgba(64,13,104,1), rgba(139,21,186,1));
}

.box > div,
.box > div > div > div {
  /* hexagon shape (https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) */
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.box > div > div > div  {
  padding-top: 91%; /* keep the ratio of the shape */
}

.box > div > div > div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-10%;
  left:-10%;
  right:-10%;
  bottom:-10%;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/800/800) center/cover;
  transform:rotate(20deg); /* rotate the image back */
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>                                  
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: that's the closest answer i guess.